# Is the expression to "mature with age" a tautology?

Tags: meaning

Given that to mature is to develop over time and that age is time-dependent, isn't "with age" redundant?

Comment: Is there possibly a sense in which the verb 'mature' is commonly used which means more than the stark 'develop over time'?

Comment: I could name several people who have not matured with age.

Answer (score 4):

I think the expression uses "mature" in this sense:

> Having or showing characteristics, such as patience and prudence, considered typical of well-balanced adulthood:

[source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mature)

One would hope people will mature with age ... but some people don't.  Instead they may continue with their sophomoric pranks and risky behavior far beyond the age when they are expected to become "mature" members of society.

Comment: +1. However the question involves a wider sense of the verb to *mature* - what about wine etc? The fact is that whilst "age" refers merely to the mathematical passage of time, "mature" incorporates many other characteristics, often associated with ageing, but for practical purposes having the possibility of being divorced from it.